# Accessing active union member

Tags: c++, c++14, unions

Is there a simple way to understand which `union` member is active?

An example:

```
union Read_Value{
 char ch;
 float number;
 string str;
}
```

Suppose a void function reads from an input file stream and initialise `Read_Value` on the base of the type of the variable read. Assuming I don't know how the function works, how can I understand which of the three member is active?

Comment: [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (C++17) might help.

Comment: the usual way is to store a 'type' variable which indicates which field is valid

Answer (score 5):

A bare `union` cannot tell you which is the active element. You have to keep track of that yourself.

---

Since C++17 `std::variant` is the "modern `union`". It has a `index()` method that tells you which is the active index. Example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index):

> ```
> #include <variant>
> #include <string>
> #include <iostream>
> int main()
> {
>     std::variant<int, std::string> v = "abc";
>  
>     std::cout << "v.index = " << v.index() << '\n';
>  
>     v = {}; 
>  
>     std::cout << "v.index = " << v.index() << '\n';
> }
> ```
>
> Possible output:
>
> ```
> v.index = 1
> v.index = 0
> ```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way to understand which `union` member is active?

In general, using a *tagged (or discriminated) union*. This means storing some metadata (tracking which member is active) alongside the raw `union`.

The modern solution is indeed [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), which does all this for you.

If you don't have C++17 support, don't have it in your standard library's experimental or tr extensions, and for some reason can't use the [Boost.variant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html) precursor ... you can still write an old-style tagged union yourself.

I wouldn't call it *simple* though, at least not to do well.